# How to retrieve the login of the user who checked-out a given file

Tags: caml-query, caml, check-out, login

I am currently developping a C# application which has to retrieve some data from a SharePoint website through a CAML request.

I successfully get everything I need except one information : the login of the user who checked out a file.

For example, if the user who checked out a file use a login looking like "john.doe", the CheckoutUser retrieved by the request is "Doe, John".

Since I need to compare the credentials of the local user with the ones of the user who checked the file, this is annoying.

Does anyone have an idea on how I could achieve that?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

This code seems to work well in my situation:

```
public User GetCurrentUser()
{ 
    using (ClientContext clientContext = _GetClientContext())
    {
        var web = clientContext.Web;
        clientContext.Load(web);
        clientContext.Load(web.CurrentUser);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        return clientContext.Web.CurrentUser;
    }
}
```

Then, we compare this user's ID with the CheckedOutUserID accessible through CAML request.
So finally, we didn't figure out how to retrieve the needed login through SharePoint web service request, but this work around seems to do the job well.

Comment: "Doe, John" might be the "Name" property of the user, you can get the same value  in c# using SPUser class's "Name" property.

Comment: the problem is that I request the webservice of the SharePoint site to retrieve the data I need, since I cannot have a development environment with SharePoint and Visual Studio on the same computer. As a result, I cannot use classes like SPUser, which are in Microsoft.SharePoint.dll, and can only request the API using CAML and parse the result "manually". Isn't there a way to do the trick with my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the edit for the workaround we finally used in our context. It doesn't do the exact same thing, but still do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for coming back with your findings, but it's clearer if you put the answer in the answer rather than editing the question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you CAML query has returned the item collection you can do

```
foreach(SPListItem item in collection)
{
    SPFieldUserValue userValue = new SPFieldUserValue(web, item["CheckoutUser"].ToString());
    SPUser checkoutUser= userValue.User;
   //Here you can compare with SPWeb.CurrentUser.ID and checkoutUser.ID
}
```

Comment: the problem is that I request the webservice of the SharePoint site to retrieve the data I need, since I cannot have a development environment with SharePoint and Visual Studio on the same computer. As a result, I cannot use classes like SPUser, which are in Microsoft.SharePoint.dll, and can only request the API using CAML and parse the result "manually".
Isn't there a way to do the trick with my configuration?

Comment: One question. How do yo want compare the credentials? By the NT login name?

Comment: By comparing it either with the user account executing the application, or to the credentials that he entered in a configuration file accessible by the application.

Comment: Can you post your C# code that calls the webservice so that I can help you better?

Comment: We found a workaround for our problem, see the edit. Thanks for your answers :)